# WPF TabItem Grid Contents Disappear Halfway Down

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabs

I have a strange problem. I have a TabControl created like so:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="10">
...
</TanControl>
```

with a few tabs created like so:

```
<TabItem Header="XXXX" Name="tab1">
...
</TabItem>
```

Inside each tab I have a grid, following the code generated by the toolbox drag and drop, I started adding data to the first control like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label001" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,34" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label002" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,62" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label003" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,90" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label004" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,130" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label005" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,158" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label006" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,186" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label007" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,226" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label008" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,254" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label009" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="XXXX" Margin="1,254" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lbl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="XXXX:" Margin="1,282" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="label010" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="XXXX" Margin="1,282" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lbl2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
</Grid>
```

The problem is, after a label is placed farther down than halfway in the grid, it disappears. If I resize the window to be bigger, I can see more items because they are no longer past halfway, if I make it smaller then more disappear because they pass the halfway point.

I have tried adding rows to the grid and they still disappear! The strange part is if I add n rows and split the labels up between them, each row gets cut off at the halfway point in each row.

This problem also shows in the design view, but only if a vertical limit is imposed like row height or window max height (because the design view stretches the containers to fit all the contents as I add them).

And finally, the columns never disappear halfway no matter how small they get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Margin="20,50" will be interpreted to mean a Thickness
>   with Left and Right set to 20, and Top and Bottom set to 50. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FRAMEWORKELEMENT.MARGIN%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true)

So, the margin "1,282" of the last label is the same with "1,282,1,282"(left,top,right,bottom). The simple way to slove your problem is to modify the margin of every label to "X,X,1,0".

You are using Margin to control a position of each control but I recommend you to use attached properties of Layout Controls of WPF to control a position. For example, for Gird there are Gird.Row and Grid.Column and for DockPannel there are Dock.Top and Dock.Left etc. For this issue, please refer to [Use Automatic Layout Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748828.aspx).

Comment: Okay, adding the left and top margins back into the labels has fixed the problem. From what I've gathered, when you set Margin="i,j", i is the margin from the HorizontalAlignment and j is the margin from the VerticalAlignment. The positions of my elements reflect this. I would understand if my positions were wrong, but since they're right, I don't understand what would make them disappear. I'll accept your answer because it fixed my problem, but I'd like to know more.

Comment: If you set Margin of Label as 1,282, which is the same with 1,282,1,282 and the height of the main window is less than 282*2, then the Label will not be displayed because of having not enough space. You can set Margin as 1,282,1,0 to display the Label with the correct position. I recommend you to set Background of the Label to identify the area of the Label like `<Label Grid.Column="1" Content="XXXX" Margin="1,282" Background="Yellow" />`